# Can I use the "Be founded on" for expressing the concept that is neither yet proved nor a theory?

Tags: word-choice

all

I would like to say "Our attack is established under the following assumption", but using the phrasal verb such as "be founded on"

for example

```
The attack is founded on the following assumptions: 
1. blah blah
2. blah blah
```

However, it seems that the "be founded on" is usually used for a theory,
but our attack is not really a theory but just a fact.

Or what about "built on" but it seems that it doesn't make sense

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean attack as in 'the basis of your approach'? Why not just use "Our approach is based on ...'?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin **The** answer of course, but +1 for submitting it as a 'comment'.

Comment: Take care to distinguish the verbs _find_ (with past tense / past participle _found_) and _found_ (with past tense / past participle _founded_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions, ideas, beliefs, etc., all may serve as the foundation of an attack, a defense, other ideas and assumptions, etc. This is standard usage.

Amherst College: "In a society founded on the assumption that all men are created equal, little progress has been made in assuring equality in education."

New York Times: "That, in a nutshell, is the challenge the United States faces as it embarks on a new military strategy founded on the assumption of its continued superiority in technologies such as robotics and artificial intelligence."

From the Library of Congress (www.loc.gov): The American republic was founded on a set of beliefs that were tested during the Revolutionary War.

Paul Ryan (from The Daily Caller): “America is the only nation founded on an idea — not an identity.

Barack Obama: “Our country was founded on the idea of religious freedom, and we have long upheld the belief that how we pray and whether we pray are matters reserved for an individual's own conscience.”